# Lagrangian of a bead free to move on the spoke of a bike wheel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I am trying out this system for a final project in my Physics class.

[image]

So the wheel is vertical as in a bike wheel and it is being driven so that the wheel is not a part of the system or the Lagrangian. However, the system is then rheonomous and therefore has a time dependence. So far I have
$$L=  \frac 12 m(r^2+r^2 \theta^2)- mgr\sin(\theta).$$

Basically I was just wondering if this Lagrangian was correct, or if there is anything else I need to add?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am wondering if my Lagrangian is correct for the system.

Comment: I think you forgot the time derivatices in your kinetic energy, which should be $m(\dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2) / 2$. Now you should apply the condition of the spinning wheel, which is $\dot{\theta} =\omega$ and $\theta = \omega t$.